# Find regex and add to the end of the document in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I have a few files following the following format:

```
ABC 123 <a href="link">XYZ<a/> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link">UVW</a>. etc.
```

I want to extract all the instances of XYZ's and UVW's and add them to the end of the document, like so:

```
ABC 123 <a href="link">XYZ<a/> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link">UVW</a>. etc. XYZ, UVW
```

Is there a way to do this with Notepad++?

What I have so far is how to capture individual instances of `<a href="link">XYZ<a/>`, extracting the `XYZ` part via the `(.*?)/$1` etc. But I am not sure how to paste that content to the end of document (presumably through `$`), nor how to capture all the instances (XYZ, UVW, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve modified your example by applying the following changes:

1. replaced manually `<a/>` with `</a>` as I considered it as a typo.
2. added couple of new lines and diversified the number of occurrences in each line to check the robustness of the regex expression

Finally the output I’ve use is as follows:

```
ABC 123 <a href="link100">Desc100</a> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link101">Desc101</a>. etc.1
ABC 123 <a href="link102">Desc102</a> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link103">Desc103</a>. etc.2
ABC 123 <a href="link104">Desc104</a> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link105">Desc105</a>. etc.ABC 123 <a href="link106">Desc106</a> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link107">Desc107</a>. etc.3
ABC 123 <a href="link108">Desc108</a> DEF 456. GHI 789 <a href="link109">Desc109</a>ABC 123 <a href="link110">Desc110</a>. etc.4
```

It's important to make a copy of the original document.
In N++
Ctrl+H
Find what: `(.*?<a href="(?<url>[^"]*)">(?<description>.*?)<\/a>)(?(?!(.*?<a href="(?<url>[^"]*)">.*?<\/a>))(.*?$)|())`
Replace with: `$+{description},` // the delimiter is comma but any other character can be used instead
Wrap around: checked
Search Mode → select 'Regular expression' AND '. Matches newline': checked
Click on 'Replace All' button.

Obtained output: 
`Desc100,Desc101,Desc102,Desc103,Desc104,Desc105,Desc106,Desc107,Desc108,Desc109,Desc110,`

This operation leaves the document with all the required instances. Now this content can be appended to the original document either manually or programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for this. `<a/>` was indeed a typo. I am not quite sure how the obtained output can be appended to the original document though. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you want something from Notepad++ you can use plugins.
[Install 'Combine' plugin]
N++ Menu | Plugins | Plugin Manager | Show Plugin Manager | Available tab
select 'Combine'
Click Install
Click 'Yes' to restart N++

[Run 'Combine' plugin]
N++ Menu | Plugins | Combine | Start
(Optionally if you have lots of text for better readibility you can select 'Insert line' in 'Before text' section)
In 'After text' section select 'Insert linefeed' (Also optional)
Click 'OK'  <br/>
A new file will be created with contents of the two files separated by new line.